# Algorithm used by Kinect SDK to calculate joint orientations

Tags: algorithm, kinect

I was wondering if anybody had any ideas what algorithm is used in the newly released Kinect SDK to provide joint orientations.

I presume they are using a more sophisticated approach than simply calculating the quaternion between the vectors describing neighbouring bone segments.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they're using a new algorithm in the new SDK,

IMO their still using the [Randomized decision forests](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/BodyPartRecognition.pdf) to estimate the Joint position and then they 'simply' calculate the quaternion based on the position of the joints returned by the skeletal tracking pipeline (link not available anymore).

For the seated tracking now available they've made training set in order to detect such a position of the user.

once again that's my opinion.

Comment: How does Kinect calculate quaternion using the positions of the joints. The link in the answer doesn't seem to be working. Do you have another reference for this?. Thanks!